# How to prevent DataFrame to be created Twice / Working with Multi DataFrames

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have two data sources that contain similar data and want to compare them with scala spark code. Currently I have the code below, but I see in the Spark UI that my rawData DataFrame is being created twice, pulling in 40GB from a raw file, I see this in the excution of my code in the SparkUI with Job0 and Job1. How can I prevent it from pulling the data twice? Am I using spark correctly with multiple data frames?

```
    // Create the sql context.
    val sqlContext = new SQLContext(context)

    // Pull the data from database, then filter down to what would be outputting, and finally place it in a DataFrame.
    val databaseDF: DataFrame = DataFrameUtils.getDataBaseDataInDataFrame.persist(StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK)

    // Pull the data from the raw file into a DataFrame.
/** THIS IS CREATED TWICE, FROM WHAT I SEE IN THE SPARK UI **/
    val rawDF: DataFrame = DataFrameUtils.getRawDataInDataFrame(sqlContext, filePath).persist(StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK)

    // Grab the counts for the report using the DataFrames and comparing them.
    val sourceTeacherCountDF: DataFrame = DataFrameUtils.getTeacherCountDF(rawDF).persist(StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK)
    val TeacherCoverageCountDF: DataFrame = DataFrameUtils.getTeacherCoverageCountDF(gemDF).persist(StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK)
    val classCountDF: DataFrame = DataFrameUtils.getclasstCountDF(gemDF).persist(StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK)
    val falseNegativeDF: DataFrame = DataFrameUtils.getFalseNegativeCountDF(rawDF, gemDF).persist(StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK)
    val falsePositiveDF: DataFrame = DataFrameUtils.getFalsePositivesCountDF(rawDF, gemDF, sqlContext).persist(StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK)


    var report: DataFrame = rawDF.select(CLASS).unionAll(gemDF.select(CLASS)).distinct()
    report = sqlContext.createDataFrame(report.map{case (Row(class: String)) =>
      Row(iavm, lookupIavmTitle(class), lookupClassNum(class))}, lookupClassDesc)

    val report: DataFrame = report.join(clasCountDF, Seq(class), "left")
      .join(teacherCountDF, Seq(class), "left")
      .join(teacherCoverageCountDF, Seq(class), "left")
      .join(falseNegativeDF, Seq(class), "left")
          .join(falsePositiveDF, Seq(class), "left").na.fill(0, report.columns)

report.write
      .format("json")
      .mode("overwrite")
      .save(outputFileName)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason it is creating twice is that

```
 val falseNegativeDF: DataFrame = DataFrameUtils.getFalseNegativeCountDF(rawDF, gemDF).persist(StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK)
 val falsePositiveDF: DataFrame = DataFrameUtils.getFalsePositivesCountDF(rawDF, gemDF, sqlContext).persist(StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK)
```

It is being used twice to create `falseNegetiveDF` and `falsePositiveDF`

I see you have persisted the rawDF but in spark persist is also a lazy operation. So if you don't want rawDF to be generated twice you need to foce the computation by doing some action on the rawDF like `rawDF.count`